# Make a searchable script in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi im new to Jquery and trying to get to grips with it, I have 160,000 documents all of are formatted in this style

> {"Player":{"FirstName":"Giovanni","LastName":"Pasquale","CommonName":null,"Height":"182","DateOfBirth":{"Year":"1982","Month":"1","Day":"5"},"PreferredFoot":"Left","ClubId":"55","LeagueId":"31","NationId":"27","Rating":"73","Attribute1":"77","Attribute2":"63","Attribute3":"70","Attribute4":"69","Attribute5":"74","Attribute6":"65","Rare":"0","ItemType":"PlayerD"}}

I want to make the players first and last name searchable and then once clicked display their Rating, Attribute1, Attribute 2, Attribute 3,4 and 5.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Thank god there is only one answer!

Answer (score 0):

Import your documents into a database (MySql for example) and create a fulltextindex over the desired fields.

[this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/full-text-search-using-mysql-full-text-search-capabilities/) should get you started.